# How to connect java to firebase using the Firebase REST API?

Tags: java, firebase

The following is a demo java code provided by firebase API. How do I use it? There seems to be no way to import the maven packages into my own project.

```
    package net.thegreshams.firebase4j.demo;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import net.thegreshams.firebase4j.error.FirebaseException;
    import net.thegreshams.firebase4j.error.JacksonUtilityException;
    import net.thegreshams.firebase4j.model.FirebaseResponse;
    import net.thegreshams.firebase4j.service.Firebase;

    import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;

    public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FirebaseException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, JacksonUtilityException {


    // get the base-url (ie: 'http://gamma.firebase.com/username')
    String firebase_baseUrl = null;
    for( String s : args ) {

        if( s == null || s.trim().isEmpty() ) continue;
        if( s.trim().split( "=" )[0].equals( "baseUrl" ) ) {
            firebase_baseUrl = s.trim().split( "=" )[1];
        }
    }
    if( firebase_baseUrl == null || firebase_baseUrl.trim().isEmpty() ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Program-argument 'baseUrl' not found but required" );
    }


    // create the firebase
    Firebase firebase = new Firebase( firebase_baseUrl );


    // "DELETE" (the fb4jDemo-root)
    FirebaseResponse response = firebase.delete();


    // "PUT" (test-map into the fb4jDemo-root)
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    dataMap.put( "PUT-root", "This was PUT into the fb4jDemo-root" );
    response = firebase.put( dataMap );
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of PUT (for the test-PUT to fb4jDemo-root):\n" + response );
    System.out.println("\n");


    // "GET" (the fb4jDemo-root)
    response = firebase.get();
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of GET:\n" + response );
    System.out.println("\n");


    // "PUT" (test-map into a sub-node off of the fb4jDemo-root)
    dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    dataMap.put( "Key_1", "This is the first value" );
    dataMap.put( "Key_2", "This is value #2" );
    Map<String, Object> dataMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    dataMap2.put( "Sub-Key1", "This is the first sub-value" );
    dataMap.put( "Key_3", dataMap2 );
    response = firebase.put( "test-PUT", dataMap );
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of PUT (for the test-PUT):\n" + response );
    System.out.println("\n");


    // "GET" (the test-PUT)
    response = firebase.get( "test-PUT" );
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of GET (for the test-PUT):\n" + response );
    System.out.println("\n");


    // "POST" (test-map into a sub-node off of the fb4jDemo-root)
    response = firebase.post( "test-POST", dataMap );
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of POST (for the test-POST):\n" + response );
    System.out.println("\n");


    // "DELETE" (it's own test-node)
    dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    dataMap.put( "DELETE", "This should not appear; should have been DELETED" );
    response = firebase.put( "test-DELETE", dataMap );
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of PUT (for the test-DELETE):\n" + response );
    response = firebase.delete( "test-DELETE");
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of DELETE (for the test-DELETE):\n" + response );
    response = firebase.get( "test-DELETE" );
    System.out.println( "\n\nResult of GET (for the test-DELETE):\n" + response );

}

}
```

The API developers also gave the following message for the firebase_url which is null in the above code:

> "In order to use this project, you must first acquire a Firebase workspace-url. You can obtain a workspace-url by signing up for early-access to their private-beta."

Question: what does the second sentence mean? Could someone make that clearer? I really need the workspace-url

Comment: This code seems extremely old. Given the references to `gamma.firebase.com` and `private-beta` I estimate it at about 5 years old. While spelunking through historical code may be interesting, it is hardly the easiest way to learn to use Firebase. Instead I recommend that you start on the Firebase documentation, which nowadays has pretty good support for Java too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: In the link provided by you for Java, there are only gradle and maven as the two options for setting up the project. Can we not use a simple Java project for such a Java-Firebase connectivity?

Comment: https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=a%3A%22firebase-admin%22&a=firebase-admin ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is correct. I am the author of Firebase4J and as much as I love seeing people's interest in the project, it was more of a POC than anything else. I barely support it to be honest, for lack of time/interest; mostly I just vet other's people's pull-requests. I haven't even kept-up with Firebase these days; if my project fills a gap that Firebase's own stuff can't, then by all means use my code -- but not until you know the official support won't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of [firebase4j](https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j).

As much as I love seeing people's interest in my project, it is very dated and not well-supported (for lack of time and interest); I approve other people's pull-requests to it but otherwise am not really maintaining it much. It was started as a POC and then one day I woke up and people were just using it (totally fine by me, but buyer-beware and all that). If this project actually fills a gap that is not provided by the official tooling, then I am totally open to people submitting pull-requests for new features and keeping the project going; but when I created this project I wrapped the Firebase REST API because they had no official Java support -- however, these days, that is no longer true ([they do!](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)).

Nevertheless, to answer the actual question asked here, I cite from the project's README:

> In order to use this project, you must first acquire a Firebase workspace-url. You can obtain a workspace-url by signing up for early-access to their private-beta.
>
> Alternatively, you can run through their tutorial and then use the auto-generated workspace-url the tutorial provides you with. This url, however, is transient so don't put any data in there you want to keep around.
>
> You should also review the Firebase documentation and tutorial, as this interface is only meant to provide a thin wrapper around their REST API.

So, first consider that the documentation refers to Firebase's "early-access to their private-beta" -- that condition is no longer relevant. But basically it's just telling you to go to Firebase and sign-up for a developer-account; you can do that by signing into Firebase at firebase.google.com.

Regarding the workspace-url, that's just a reference to your Firebase-workspace that gets created when you define a Firebase-project at firebase.google.com. It is not in scope here to walk you through that, but I'm sure the tutorials cover it -- and by the time you are done reading their tutorials, you will probably decide to use the tooling that they provide today (which they did not when I wrote Firebase4j).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I have updated the project's README to reflect the above.

Comment: The admin SDK is not an alternative as it gives full Admin access and can't be used for JAVA clients.

Comment: No java support on your linked page

Comment: You're right. I was thinking that the server-side SDK would be sufficient for most and that the web API would suffice for client-side only. If that's not the case, can you please clarify for me what you are asking from me?

Comment: I have a Java client application with UI in JavaFX. There is no webdriver in this application and i would like to avoid adding one and writing a complex sync between both.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I have moved on to other hobbies but as I've said if you'd like to add what you need and send me a pull-request, I'd be happy to add it to the project for others to also benefit!